# How to use the locater to find the specifc word with protractor if dont have the id?

Tags: protractor, ui-automation

recently I'm study on how to use those locaters in protractor to perform the test.

But how can I locate if don't have the id inside?

For example in my screenshot, How can I locate the words "You do not have rights to access this page, Please obtain your" or "Access" in a tag?

[image]

Comment: try `by.css('span[ng-bind-html="AccessDenied.HtmlMsg"]')`

Answer (score 0):

review this page for all possible locator strategies https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText

In your case, cssContainingText seems to be the most appropriate, but you can also fo with xpath and just css if you learn how to use attributes other than id